# External Css not working in Gatsby react project

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am not sure if this is the correct way of using CSS in gatsby but for some reason my external syles are not being applied in gatsby project.

This is what I am doing it

```
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import React from "react"
import "./header.css"

const Header = (props) => {
  return (
  <header
    style={{
      background: `black`,
      marginBottom: `1.45rem`,
    }}
  >
    <div
      style={{
        margin: `0 auto`,
        maxWidth: 960,
        padding: `1.45rem 1.0875rem`,
      }}
    >
      <h1 style={{ margin: 0 }}>
        <Link
          to="/"
          style={{
            color: `white`,
            textDecoration: `none`,
          }}
        >
          {props.siteTitle} <span className="header-description"> {props.description} </span>
        </Link>
      </h1>
    </div>
  </header>
  )
}

Header.propTypes = {
  siteTitle: PropTypes.string,
}

Header.defaultProps = {
  siteTitle: ``,
}

export default Header
```

and this is my `header.css`

```
.header-description {
  font-size: 12;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your css is invalid. `font-size` can't have unitless values except for `0`.

Maybe you wanted it to be `12px`?

Answer (score 0):

what i usually do is create and import index.css into layer component (or any other wrapping component) aaaand then import individual/uniques/modules to that index.css.  So the main index.css becomes sort of like a hub for css files which then is being imported only in once place. well, obviously if you would use css modules you would have to import them into your react components, but by the looks of it you are just using classnames. so...yea, try my method, maybe that helps? Theres also like 4 tutorials on how to import and use css and various styling methodologies in gatsby docs.